# Emacs align-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, eval

I am new to Emacs. I want to use `align-regexp` so that I can align my text based on square bracket `[`.
I am able to do this from GUI like this `M-x align-regexp`: `\[`
I want to create an alias using `emacs --eval` since I use this frequently.
I did some thing like this

```
emacs <filename> --eval "(progn (mark-whole-buffer) (align-regexp \[))"
```

This selects whole buffer. But nothing after that. 
Please help me to do it.

Comment: I tried like this also
emacs f1 --eval "(progn (mark-whole-buffer) (align-regexp (concat "\\ ( \\s-*\\ ) \[")))"
But it says badly placed ()'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emacs -batch f1 --eval '(align-regexp (point-min) (point-max) "\\(\\s-*\\)\\[" 1 1 nil)' -f save-buffer
```

where `f1` is the file name.

Comment: where f1 is filename